# set header correctly...images float right h1 title

Tags: html, css

This is my page:
http://clouderize.it/demo/index.html

I would set the header like in this image:
[image]

What I am doing wrong with css property?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the div with the ball before the h1-element.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
<div style="position: absolute;top: 5px;right: 5px;"><img style="width:30px" src="themes/images/ball.jpg"></div>
```

See `float:right` is replaced with `position: absolute;top: 5px;right: 5px;`

Answer (score 0):

Put your image into the h1 element, before the text:

```
<h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">
   <div style="float:right">
      <img src="themes/images/ball.jpg" style="width:30px">
   </div>
   0.1!
</h1>
```

and then fix css like this:

```
.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title {
    ...
    margin: 0.6em auto 0.8em;
}
```